# Another Probability Magic?

Tags: probability

Carefully see this problem(I have solved them on my own, I'm only talking about the magical coincidence):

> A bag contains 6 notes of 100 Rs.,2 notes of 500 Rs., 3 notes of 1000 Rs..Mr. A draws two notes from the bag then Mr. B draws 2 notes from the bag.
>   (i)Find the probability that A has drawn 600 Rs.
>   (ii)Find the probability that B has drawn 600 Rs.
>   (iii)B has drawn 600 Rs., then find the probability that A has also drawn 600 Rs..
>   (iv)A has drawn 600 Rs.,then find the probability that B has drawn 600 Rs.
>
> ---
>
> (i)$$P=\frac{\binom61\binom21}{\binom{11}2}=\frac{12}{55}$$
>   (ii)**Total Probability Theorem:** Considering various cases, depending upon what A chooses:
>    In order of $2H,2F,2T,1H1T,1H1F,1F1T$
>  where H=100(**H**undred),F=500(**F**ive-hundred),T=1000(**T**housand)]is:
>   $$P=\frac{\binom41\binom21}{\binom92}\frac{\binom62}{\binom{11}2}
> +\frac{0}{\binom92}\frac{\binom22}{\binom{11}2}
> +\frac{\binom61\binom21}{\binom92}\frac{\binom32}{\binom{11}2}
> +\frac{\binom51\binom21}{\binom92}\frac{\binom61\binom31}{\binom{11}2}
> +\frac{\binom51\binom11}{\binom92}\frac{\binom61\binom21}{\binom{11}2}
> +\frac{\binom61\binom11}{\binom92}\frac{\binom21\binom31}{\binom{11}2}=\frac{12}{55}$$
>   **Oh My God!What's happening here above?**
>   (iii)**Baye's Theorem:** $$P=\frac{\frac{\binom51\binom11}{\binom92}\frac{\binom61\binom21}{\binom{11}2}}{\frac{12}{55}}=\frac5{36}$$
>   (iv)**Conditional Probability:** $$P(B|A)=\frac{P(AB)}{P(A)}=\frac{\frac{\binom51\binom11}{\binom92}\frac{\binom61\binom21}{\binom{11}2}}{\frac{12}{55}}=\frac5{36}$$
>   **Not again, you must be joking!**

Why doesn't it makes any difference?Think Intutively, if A has taken some money there must be less notes so there must be difference in probability, why doesn't order matter here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where A takes some of the bills that will make 600, yes, the probability that B can also get 600 goes down, but in the cases where A takes some bills that do not contribute to a combination of 600, the probability B can get 600 goes up!  So it balances out to be the same.

You can also see why the order of A and B does not matter by reversing time and imagine each wrote their name on the bills they chose and put them back in the bag.  Regardless of the order they picked, two of them are for A and two are for B.

Comment: So it balances out to be the same, can you prove it, for all cases?The second para is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

> > (i)Find the probability that A has drawn 600 Rs.

Only $A$ is drawing. It doesn't matter if he picks the $100$ or $500$ first. So order does not matter.

> > (ii)Total Probability Theorem: Considering various cases, depending upon what A chooses:
> >     In order of 2H,2F,2T,1H1T,1H1F,1F1T
> >     where H=100(Hundred),F=500(Five-hundred),T=1000(Thousand)]is:

It's actually broken down into cases pretty well. If $A$ chose $2H$, the odds are: $\binom{6}{2}/\binom{11}{2}$. We then multiply this by the odds of $B$ getting $600$ given this, which are $\binom{4}{1} \binom{2}{1}/\binom{9}{2}$.

So the idea is this: we break $A$'s outcomes down into cases. For a given case, we then examine what is left and calculate $B$'s odds. Then by rule of product, we multiply. Each case is disjoint, so we add up the results. Does this make sense?

> > (iv)A has drawn 600 Rs.,then find the probability that B has drawn 600 Rs.

So there are $5H$ and $1F$ left. The odds of getting 600 are:

$$\frac{ \binom{5}{1} \binom{1}{1} }{\binom{9}{2} } = \frac{5}{36}$$

Notice that I didn't go through the whole process with Bayes' Theorem. I just cut to the chase by analyzing the cases.

Notice as well that the order in which $B$ or $A$ choose their respective bills do not matter. It just matters that we are careful about analyzing what is left after $A$'s turn.

Note- if you want me to go through $3$, I will be happy to do so. Just comment and let me know.

Comment: Sorry to say but I think you understood that I have posted the answers of a question and am wanting explanations to it, but this is not the case because I solved them on my own and found the coincidently same values.So sorry, thanks for your effort

Comment: Sorry for my confusion then! I guess I'm not entirely clear on what you were asking. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't it makes any difference?  Think Intutively, if A has taken some money there must be less notes so there must be difference in probability, why doesn't order matter here?

Think counterintuitively.   A has taken two notes but we *don't know what they are* when measuring the probability that B has a certain amount.

It's like shuffling a deck of cards.   It should not matter if we shuffle the deck or build the deck by picking cards out of a bag one after another.    Either way there's an *equal* probability that each of the 52 cards are in *any* particular position in the deck.

Does your intuition suggest that because *some* card is on top of the deck it affects the probability that the second card is an ace — when we don't know what that card might be?   Are the following answers surprising?

1. Find the probability that an Ace is on top of the deck.$$\mathsf P(A_1)=\frac{4}{52}$$
2. Find the probability that an Ace is second from the top.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A_2) & = \mathsf P(A_1)\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)+\mathsf P(\neg A_1)\mathsf P(A_2\mid\neg A_1) \\ & = \frac{4}{52}\frac{3}{51}+\frac{48}{52}\frac{4}{51} \\ & =\frac{4}{52}\end{align}$$
3. An Ace is on top of the deck, find the probability that another Ace is second from the top.$$\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)=\frac{3}{51}$$
4. An Ace is second in the deck, find the probability that another Ace is on top.$$\mathsf P(A_1\mid A_2)=\frac{\mathsf P(A_1)\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)}{\mathsf P(A_2)}=\frac{\frac{4}{52}\frac{3}{51}}{\frac{4}{52}}=\frac{3}{51}$$

Comment: but the difference is that A has gone away with the money so the probability that B will take 600 depends on what A takes, it might that there's no possible way to do that for B, in your case wherever the first ace may be it doesn't affect the other ace

Comment: Then imagine the notes are shuffled and not taken away at first, but it is determined that the top two notes go to A and the next two go to B.  Then they can take their money.  Instead of them being in a bag, just imagine them hidden, but shuffled in a certain order.